# main class and controller loader

Tags: php, oop, controllers

I'm trying to learn OOP and just for testing I want to create a main class with different methods. In this case, I want to "load" a controller like CodeIgniter:

```
$app->load->controller('test')
```

`load()` is a method of `Main()` but what about `controller()` ?

This is what I have so far, but obviously it is not working. I can't understand how to pass the controller name to the Load/controller class

```
class Main {
    public function load()
    {
        $loader = new Load();
        $loader->controller('index');
    }
}

class Load {
    public function controller($class)
    {
        $class = ucfirst($class);
        $class = new $class();
        $class->index();    
    }
}

class Test {
    function index()
    {
        echo 'class: test - method: index';
    }
}

$main = new Main;
$controller = $main->load->controller('test');
```

Comment: Your Main::Load method is supposed to return an instance of Load rather than working on it itself, i.e., `return new Load();` - then `$main->load()->controller('test');` should work.

Comment: yo mean `class Main {
 public function load()
 {
  return new Load;
 }
}` ? tried that but... Fatal error: Call to a member function controller() on a non-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this

```
class Main {

    public function load()
    {
        //include "Load.php";
        return new Load();
    }

}

class Load {

    public function controller($class = '')
    {
        if( file_exists( $class . '.php') ) {
            include $class . '.php';
            $class = ucfirst($class);
            return new $class;
        }
    }

}

$main = new Main;
$controller = $main->load()->controller('testClass');
$controller->index(); // Assume testClass has an index method
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D2gfOU)

Comment: the Load class is in the same file why do you use include "Load.php" ?

Comment: I assumed it is in a different file.

Comment: See the changes and try again, it should work, anyways, Your `php` version should be `PHP5 +`

Comment: ohh i see i was using $main->load->controller('testClass'); instead of $main->load()->controller('testClass'); and now works great!. one more question: what if i have two methods in the Main() ? load() and input() for example ??

Comment: You can keep two methods on the main.

Comment: @handsome, You can call `$main->input()` if you have another `input` method.

Comment: the Main class returns new Load; how can i handle that? using a switch?

Comment: Main doesn't return `Load` unless you call `Main::load`

Comment: there is one more thing: how can i call Load->controller() from testClass->index() ??

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main 
{
    public function load()
    {
        $loader = new Load();
        $loader->controller('index');
    }
}
class Load 
{
    public function controller($class)
    {
        $test=new Test();
        $test->index();    
    }
}
class Test 
{
    function index()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
$main = new Main();
$main->load('test');
```

Comment: Could yo explain why this works and what was wrong in OP's example?